# how to get value of multi ul list

Tags: jquery

This is of my code

```
     <ul class="nav nav-pills ranges"  id="date_range">
          <li class="active"><a href="#" data-range='1' data-toggle="tab">Last Day</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" data-range='7'>Last Week</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" data-range='30'>Last Month</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills ranges"  id="data_type">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-type='timeInMs' data-toggle="tab">Response</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-type='speed_download'>Speed Download</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-type='dnsTime'>DNS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-type='size'>Page Size</a></li>
```

I want get value of data-range and data-type with each li active

this is my code

```
$('ul.ranges a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the number of days from the data attribute
        days = $('ul#date_range li.active a').attr('data-range');

        data_type = $('ul#date_type li.active a').attr('data-type');         

        // Make things pretty to show which button/tab the user clicked
        el.parent().addClass('active');
        el.parent().siblings().removeClass('active');



    });
```

Comment: use .data(""); instead of .attr("")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data()` and also for getting li use `closest()` as `parent()` not works if HTML is changed.

do like this:

```
    $('ul.ranges a').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();        

            $(this).closest("li").addClass('active');
            $(this).closest("li").siblings().removeClass('active');

            // Get the number of days from the data attribute
            var days = $('ul#date_range li.active a').data('range');

            var data_type = $('ul#data_type li.active a').data('type'); 

             console.log(days+":"+data_type)

        });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T44SW/1/)

Comment: and click not show current active, it's show when other active

Comment: can you little explain what you are trying?

Comment: if current active is "Last Days" and log show:  1:speed_download and i lick to "Last week" but until show 1:speed_download not show 7:speed_download , show pre value active not show active value

Comment: just get values after adding and removing active class and it will work

Comment: glad that it helped out at last..:)

Answer (score 0):

remove the `.active` class from `$('ul#date_range li.active a')` as you haven't assigned that class until later